# storing the function output to an object in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe.

```
structure(list(CONTENT = c("@_ShankarNath Hey Shankar, thank you for highlighting this to us, it will be taken care.", 
"#deals #Puma Cell Kilter Black Sneakers is selling cheaper at INR 3899 today https://t.co/n9wLwofVzz #jabong"
), MEDIA_PROVIDER = c("TWITTER", "TWITTER")), .Names = c("CONTENT", 
"MEDIA_PROVIDER"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)
```

I have an input text file and an output text file.  Input file has a field named "CONTENT".  From the data frame given above I am passing the sentence through a loop and performing some calculations.  In the output file I have a field named "Score", where the a score will be populated.  I have to extract the score and store it in an object.

I have written the following codes.

```
sco <- for (i in 1:nrow(dfa)){
  s <- list()
  filecon <- file("input.txt")
  writeLines(c("Username = ABC","Password = 123",paste("Content = ", dfa$CONTENT[i]),"Delimiter =  "), filecon)
  close(filecon)

# perform all the calculations

  a <- readLines("output.txt")
  get.score <- function(scor) {
    score <- scor[grepl("Score = ", scor)]
      as.numeric(strsplit(score, "Score = ")[[1]][2])
  }
  s <- get.score(a)
  print(s)
  }
```

The output file looks like this:

```
c("Content = @_ShankarNath Hey Shankar, thank you for highlighting this to us, it will be taken care.", 
"Delimiter =  ", "Score = 1.978", "Result = Success")
```

The value of the score get replaced with every iteration, and I am trying to capture the same, before the loop moves on to the second line.

The print score return the values for all the statements.  However when I try replacing the 
`print(s)` with `s` the function is returning `NULL`.  I tried using `return(s)` I am getting an error `Error: No function to return from, jumping to the top level`.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: why are you defining a function inside a for-loop?

Comment: @mtoto since for every input that I provide I get an output generated and pasted.  If i dont capture the output and store it, the loop moves on to the second line and I will have a new output where the old output gets replaced.  Hence, I thought I should define the function inside the loop itself.

Comment: @mtoto the print function prints the output on to the screen for every input iterated by the loop

Comment: Maybe `s[i] <- get.score(a)`, and keep `s <- list()` outside the `for loop` ?

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you...but still the getting NULL value...I am editing the question to include the output file.

Comment: you script is wired because ` for` doesn't output anything so ` sco <- for(i in  ...` doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing it so far, I suggest two alternatives, either using `apply` or `foreach` from package `foreach` as it seems what you would like to write.

```
get.score <- function(scor) {
    score <- scor[grepl("Score = ", scor)]
    as.numeric(strsplit(score, "Score = ")[[1]][2])
}

sco <- apply(dfa, 1, function(v) {
             filecon <- file("input.txt")
             writeLines(c("Username = ABC","Password = 123",paste("Content = ", v['CONTENT']),"Delimiter =  "), filecon)
             close(filecon)

             # perform all the calculations
             a <- readLines("output.txt")
             get.score(a)
})
```

This will output a matrix or vector, but depending on the output of `get.score` this might not be suitable. You can also use `lapply`

```
sco <- lapply(dfa$CONTENT, function(v) {
             filecon <- file("input.txt")
             writeLines(c("Username = ABC","Password = 123",paste("Content = ", v),"Delimiter =  "), filecon)
             close(filecon)

             # perform all the calculations
             a <- readLines("output.txt")
             get.score(a)
})
```

Finally it the `for` structure is more familiar to you, you can try

```
library(foreach)
sco <- foreach(v=dfa$CONTENT) %do% {
             filecon <- file("input.txt")
             writeLines(c("Username = ABC","Password = 123",paste("Content = ", v),"Delimiter =  "), filecon)
             close(filecon)

             # perform all the calculations
             a <- readLines("output.txt")
             get.score(a)
}
```

Not that the `foreach` package allows you to make parallel computation.

Comment: Many many thanks....was struggling with this since yesterday evening...i did use apply...but within for loop.  Your first option with apply worked.  I was under the impression, that since i have to iterate over each line probably the for loop is best suited.  Many thanks again.

Comment: the second should work also now, previously I left `,1 ,` in the `lapply` from copy/paste of the `apply` case